# WebView into a Fragment (android.support.v4)

Tags: android, webview, fullscreen, fragment

I got a tab menu using a `ViewPager`. Each tab contains fragments from android.support.v4 package (compatibility with old SDKs). One of the fragment is a `WebView` (called `FragmentWeb`) and I want it to stay into the pager layout. The problem is when my `WebView` is inflated, it runs in fullscreen mode.

Is there a way to keep web browser under my tabs ?

Thank you

My Fragment Class : **FragmentWeb.java**

```
public class FragmentWeb extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web, container, false);
    WebView webView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    return mainView;
}
}
```

My Fragment's layout : **fragment_web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done by adding the following code to your onCreateView within your fragment code and embedding a WebViewClient call:

```
                webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
            webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
            webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webview.loadUrl(mTabURL);       
        }
        return v;
    }


    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {        
        /* (non-Java doc)
         * @see android.webkit.WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)
         */


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".mp4")) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");

                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            } 
            else {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can simply adapt the current implementation of WebViewFragment to your needs by replacing:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

by

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

in your own copy of [WebViewFragment.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewFragment.java) source.