# Unable to load url in webview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I am using below code in my fragment to load html file from assets folder in my project.

```
public class PrivacyPolicyFragment extends Fragment {
    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_privacy_policy, container, false);
        myWebView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html");       
        return view;

    }
    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {        

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the xml file for the fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.deadbrains.shareyourthought.PrivacyPolicy" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/mywebview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[WebView into a Fragment (android.support.v4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279632/webview-into-a-fragment-android-support-v4?rq=1)

[Android Fragment WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137646/android-fragment-webview?rq=1)

But it doesn't load anything, nor does it gives any error. I went through many SO threads and tried different things but no luck. here are the threads that I tried.

Comment: Can you post your xml file of fragment?

Comment: @AkashSingh check the updated que

Comment: downvoter san...any valid reason for downvote plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this statement to your root `LinearLayout`

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: Did the trick...silly mistake btw...tnx a ton for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

Add `view.loadUrl(url);` inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Replace `return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);` with `return true;`